# Retrieve rows with more than 2 relations in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `table_a` and `table_b`. `table_a` has the following schema :

```
CREATE TABLE  table_a (
  a_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  a VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  b_id INT(11)
);
```

and `table_b` :

```
CREATE TABLE table_b (
  b_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  b VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Each element in `table_a` refers (in `table_a.b_id`) to one element of `table_b`.

I want a query that would output every element of `table_b` for which there are 2 elements or more referencing to it in `table_a` (and for each row, I'd like it to display how many elements in `table_a` refer to it)

Thanks

Comment: Someone correct me but shouldn't b_id be absolutely consistent in both tables (especially for FK)

Comment: What do you mean ? I'm not really familiar with foreign keys (or with mysql and sql in general to be honest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT b.b_id, b.b, t.b_count
FROM table_b b INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.b_id, COUNT(*) AS b_count
    FROM table_a a
    GROUP BY a.b_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t
ON b.b_id = t.b_id
```

This avoids a single `GROUP BY` query which would contain ambiguous columns (and therefore would not run on SQL Server and some other flavors).